# observable esta imprimiendo la data en blanco

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs

```
  private CTomatic(orders: Array<Order>): void {
const Ct = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('defaultCookingTime'));
if (orders.length > 0) {
  orders.forEach(order => {
    if (
      order.partner_order_state === ORDER_STATE.NEWORDER &&
      (window.localStorage.getItem('cookingTime') === 'true' ? true : false)
    ) {
      this.ordersService
      .takeOrder(order.id, this.cookingTime(order, Ct))
      .retry(5)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.autoPrinter();
          this.autoupdatethatshit();
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          const error = err.error ? err.error.error.message : err.statusText;
          this.snackbarService.showMessageSnackbar(error);
          this.autoupdatethatshit();
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

}

### my bug is that when i reach to this.autoPrinter(); they should print a text that is working fine, i think that the problem is on the observable but im stuck on that dont know if is something else i really need help on that !!!

tengo un problema en mi metodo Ctomaic que dentro del subscribe cuando ya tiene la data y se dispara la funcion de imprimir this.autoPrinter(), la impresion sale en blanco, no entiendo por que si la data llega bien al metodo hace lo que tiene que hacer solo que no imprime nada solo la hoja en blanco

```
public autoPrinter(): void {
if (this.notificationPrintIsEnable === true) {
  window.setTimeout(() => this.printerService.print(), 2000);
}
```

}

```
  public autoupdatethatshit(): void {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.ordersService.getOrders();
}, 5000);
```

}

//en el metodo de abajo imprime la data bien y son bastante parecidos

```
public takingOrder() {
if (!this.disabled) {
  this.disabled = true;
  this.showLoading.emit(true);
  this.ordersService
    .takeOrder(this.orderDetail.id, this.cookingTime)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.takeOrderEvent.emit({
          id: this.orderDetail.id,
          cooking_time: this.cookingTime
        });
        this.disabled = false;
        this.showLoading.emit(false);
        this.orderAccept.emit();
        this.autoPrinter();
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.showLoading.emit(false);
        const error = err.error ? err.error.error.message : err.statusText;
        this.disabled = false;
        this.snackbarService.showMessageSnackbar(error);
        this.orderAccept.emit();
      }
    );
}
```

}

Comment: edita tu pregunta, traducelo porfavor!, este es el sitio de SO en idioma español

Comment: listo, gracias por el comentario !

Comment: Andres traduce toda tu pregunta, el titulo incluido. Si no es muy probable que tengamos que cerrarla.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!